# Cross-validation in scikit-learn: mean absolute error of (X_test, y_test)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Usually we split the original feature and target data (X,y) in (X_train, y_train) and (X_test, y_test).

By using the method:

```
mae_A = cross_val_score(clf, X_train_scaled, y_train, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", cv=kfold)
```

I get the cross validation Mean Absolute Error (MAE) for the (X_train, y_train), right?

How can I get the MAE (from the previous cross-validation models got by using (X_train, y_train)) for the (X_test, y_test)?

Comment: Usually, you don't do cross-validation for train and test separately. You do it on the whole data set.

Comment: If in `cv=kfold` instead of `kfold` you use an iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices, your model will train on train indices and produce score for test indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct approach. As a rule, you should only train your model using training data.
Thus the `test_set` should remain unseen in the cross-validation process, i.e. by the model's hyperparameters, otherwise you could be biasing the results obtained from the model by adding knowledge from the test sample.

> I get the cross validation Mean Absolute Error (MAE) for the (X_train, y_train), right?

Yes, the error displayed by `cross_val_score` will be only from the training data.
So the idea is that once you are satisfied with the results of `cross_val_score`, you fit the final model with the whole training set, and perform a prediction on `y_test`. For that you could use `sklearn.metrics`. For isntance, if you wanted to obtain the [MAE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html):

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae
MAE = mae(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: @yash what you say is not correct; we *never* use the test data for *anything* during model development, save for checking the performance of our final model at the end.